# WCF EF return as list

Tags: vb.net, wcf, entity-framework

Hi I got the error when return EF as the list. Here are my codes.

WCF

```
Public Function GetMerchantList() As List(Of Merchant) Implements IMerchant.GetMerchantList
                Dim ws As New aMerchantService.MerchantServiceClient

                Dim General As New General
                Dim kWSUrl As String = ""

                Dim endpointAddress = ws.Endpoint.Address

                Dim newEndpointAddress As New EndpointAddressBuilder(endpointAddress)
                kWSUrl = General.ConvertWsURL("App")

                newEndpointAddress.Uri = New Uri(kWSUrl & "MerchantService.svc")
         ws = New aMerchantService.MerchantServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IMerchantService", newEndpointAddress.ToEndpointAddress())
                Dim Data = ws.GetMerchantList()

      Return Data
End Function
```

Merchant Class

```
Public Function GetMerchantList() As List(Of Merchant)
                Dim Db As New TTMSEntities
                Dim Data = (From p In Db.TT_MERCHANT Join r In Db.TT_BRANCH_SETTING On _
                           p.MERCHANT_BRANCH_INTERNAL_NUM Equals r.INTERNAL_NUM _
                           Select New Merchant With {.MerchantID = p.MERCHANT_ID,
                                                     .MerchantName = p.DESCRIPTION,
                                                     .BranchID = r.INTERNAL_NUM,
                                                     .BranchName = r.BRANCH_DESC})

                If Data IsNot Nothing Then
                    Return Data.ToList
                Else
                    Return Nothing
                End If
 End Function
```

> The error is Error Value of type '1-dimensional array of
>   TTMS.App.WebSites.Data.Merchant' cannot be converted to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of TTMS.Web.WebSites.WCF.Merchant)'.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using a service reference.  By default, WCF will serialize generic lists as arrays.  To override this behavior,  when you go to add the service reference, click on the Advanced button at the bottom left corner.  This will bring up the Service Reference Settings.  Select `System.Generics.List` for the collection type (the default is `System.Array`):

[image]